# Simple substring program won't work

Tags: string, visual-c++, substring

My task is to input some text in `tbUnos` and in `label1` print out string's first two letters. I've just started learning Visual C++ and I'm trying to figure things out.

> private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
>
> ```
>       String^ sUnos = tbUnos->Text;
>       label1->Text = sUnos->String::Substring(1,2);
> ```
>
> }

When built and ran, my program crashed.
Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not C++, this is C++/CLI, which is a language extension targeting the CLI.

Second, I don't understand how your program compiles when you do this `sUnos->String::Substring`. However, your code should look like this:

```
String^ sUnos = tbUnos->Text;
if(!String::IsNullOrEmpty(sUnos))
   label1->Text = sUnos->Substring(1,2);
```

EDIT: Notice this code is in the handler for the `TextChanged` event. That means it is called each time the text changes, like each time you press a key on the keyboard. When you type the first letter in the text box, the `tbUnos->Text` will contain a single character and `Substring(1, 2)` will throw because there is no index 1 to start with. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
>
> `startIndex` plus `length` indicates a position not within this instance.

Comment: I did that, ran the program and started typing letters in tbUnos. It only let me enter one letter, after which it crashed. Following message was on my screen: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: I understand. I added a button to be clicked after the input is done. It worked and I finished my project in time. Thank you!!!